# response_json = json.loads(response.stdout) not working on windows

Tags: python, json, curl

i am trying to run my code on Windows but I keep getting this error
[image: json.loads(response.stdout) error]

It works on Linux but not on Windows does anyone know why? here is my full code by the way
I have tried googling, using AI, and even my own (limited) knowledge, but I cant figure anything out, my goal is to try a version that can run on Linux and windows, so I would appreciate any ideas that can work with both OS's

```py
# -------------------Config------------------

archive_prefix = "output"
output_txt_file = "output.txt"
output_html_file = "index.html"
archive_directory = "./archive"  # You may enter a relative path (folder needs to start with ./) or you can use a specific path (C:\folder\folder2\)
# Delete or rename old files based on the value of DeleteOldItems variable
DeleteOldItems = False  # If false, old items will be stacked in another location
OutputHTML = True  # Output as an HTML file so you can open it in a browser and click on the links
HostHTML = False  # If OutputHTML = True and HostHTML = True will host on all IPs on port 8080 (to reach if hosted on a personal computer, you can access using localhost:8080 as a URL in your web browser))

# ----------------End config-----------------

import subprocess
import json
import os
from datetime import datetime

# Get the number of times to loop from user input
num_loops = int(input("How many codes would you like?\n>> "))
index = 0  # Do not change

print("")
if DeleteOldItems:
  # Delete old files if they exist
  if os.path.exists(output_txt_file):
    os.remove(output_txt_file)
  if os.path.exists(output_html_file):
    os.remove(output_html_file)
else:
  # Rename old files with timestamp if they exist
  timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
  if os.path.exists(output_txt_file):
    new_txt_file = os.path.join(archive_directory,
                                f"{archive_prefix}_{timestamp}.txt")
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(new_txt_file), exist_ok=True)
    os.rename(output_txt_file, new_txt_file)
    print(f"Old output stored as {archive_prefix}_{timestamp}.txt")
  if os.path.exists(output_html_file):
    new_html_file = os.path.join(archive_directory,
                                 f"{archive_prefix}_{timestamp}.html")
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(new_html_file), exist_ok=True)
    os.rename(output_html_file, new_html_file)
    print(f"Old output stored as {archive_prefix}_{timestamp}.html")
# Initialize an empty list to store tokens
tokens = []

# Loop the specified number of times
for _ in range(num_loops):
  # Send the POST request using cURL
  curl_command = [
      'curl', 'https://api.discord.gx.games/v1/direct-fulfillment', '-H',
      'authority: api.discord.gx.games', '-H', 'accept: */*', '-H',
      'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9', '-H',
      'content-type: application/json', '-H', 'origin: https://www.opera.com',
      '-H', 'referer: https://www.opera.com/', '-H',
      'sec-ch-ua: "Opera GX";v="105", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"',
      '-H', 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0', '-H', 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"',
      '-H', 'sec-fetch-dest: empty', '-H', 'sec-fetch-mode: cors', '-H',
      'sec-fetch-site: cross-site', '-H',
      'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/105.0.0.0 (Edition std-1)',
      '--data-raw',
      '{"partnerUserId":"e518cd9e4d526d3de4aeb6d5e36f012bba82443ef1856a68029191ac8c6d136b"}',
      '--compressed'
  ]
  response = subprocess.run(curl_command, capture_output=True, text=True)

  # Parse the JSON response
  response_json = json.loads(response.stdout)

  # Get the token from the JSON response if it exists
  token = response_json.get("token")

  # Print the token if it exists
  if token:
    # Append the token to the text file
    URL = "https://discord.com/billing/partner-promotions/1180231712274387115" + token
    if OutputHTML == False:
      with open(output_txt_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write(URL + '\n\n')
    elif OutputHTML == True:
      index += 1
      with open(output_html_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write(f"{index}. <a href=\"{URL}\">{token}</a><br>\n\n")
    # Append the token to the list
    tokens.append(token)
print("please check for an output file")
if OutputHTML == True & HostHTML == True:
  # Host the HTML file as a web server on IP 0.0.0.0 and port 8080
  os.system(f"python -m http.server 8080 --bind 0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: I would just `print` the `response.stdout` that you're trying to `json.loads`. Maybe your Windows `curl` behaves differently than your Linux one?

Comment: Please create a **minimal** reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you get empty string in `response.stdout`
so when you have `json.loads('')` it throws an error
you need to check that this `response.stdout` is not empty string before you load it with `json`.

try this :

```py
response = subprocess.run(curl_command, capture_output=True, text=True)
if response.stdout:
   response_json = json.loads(response.stdout)
   token = response_json.get("token")
```